# Strapi Sitemap Plugin Generating Only One Link Regardless of Content

Tags: strapi, sitemap

I am currently using Strapi version v4.11.5 and Node version v18.16.0 for my project. I installed the [strapi-plugin-sitemap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/strapi-plugin-sitemap#strapi-sitemap-plugin) using the command `npm install strapi-plugin-sitemap@^3` to generate a sitemap for my website. I've set the permissions for both Public and Authenticated users accordingly. However, I've stumbled upon an issue where only one link is generated in the sitemap regardless of the number of posts on my site.

Here's the detailed scenario:

1. After the initial setup, on generating the sitemap, it includes a link to just one of my posts.
2. Upon deleting that particular post and regenerating the sitemap, it then includes a link to another post, but still only a single link.
3. Despite making changes to my content or the plugin settings, the sitemap consistently includes a single link.

Here is my configuration for the sitemap plugin:

```js
'sitemap': {
      enabled: true,
      config: {
        limit: -1,
        xsl: true,
        autoGenerate: true,
        caching: true,
        allowedFields: ['id', 'uid'],
        excludedTypes: [],
      },
},
```

I have gone through the plugin documentation and forums for a possible solution but haven't found any. I am suspecting this might be a bug or perhaps a misconfiguration on my part, although I am not sure where to look next.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or has any insights on how to resolve this? Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!